# Prove that if $f^2$ is integrable in $X$, then $f$ is integrable in $X$.

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying for a test in measure theory.
Please help with the following question:
$(X,A,\mu)$ a finite measure space, and $f$ is a measurable function in $X$.
Prove that if $f^2$ is integrable in $X$, then $f$ is integrable in $X$.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: $$|f|\leqslant f^2+1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_X f d\mu &= \int_{\left\{x\in X\colon |f(x)|<1\right\}} fd\mu + \int_{\left\{x\in X\colon |f(x)|\ge1\right\}} fd\mu \\
&\le \mu(X) + \int_{\left\{x\in X\colon |f(x)|\ge1\right\}} f^2d\mu\le\\
&\le \mu(X) + \int_X f^2d\mu<\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\ldots \leq \mu(X) + \int_X f^2d\mu < \infty$?

Comment: Sure, it's my bad, I thought it was probability space.

Answer (score 1):

$|\int_X  fd\mu|=|\int_X 1\cdot fd\mu|^2\leq |\int_X 1d\mu|\cdot |\int_X|f|^2d\mu|=\mu(X)|\int_X|f|^2d\mu|<\infty$